# My Minecraft Launcher Only Has a Loading Button

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues, minecraft-launcher

I have played Minecraft for a long time and this has never happened to me before. I recently just built my computer and I am running Windows 7 Home Basic. When I run Minecraft this is the screen I see:
[image]

Can anyone help me with this problem? I am an avid Minecraft player and would like to see this problem solved as soon as possible.

Comment: As you recently built your computer, have you checked to see if other games are able to connect to the Internet?

Comment: Yes, I am able to connect to other games on Steam and everything runs perfectly.

Comment: Try switching to launcher log to see if there are any noticeable errors

Comment: I switched to it but everything seems fine... The last line says [20:35:05 INFO]: Logging in with access token what does that mean?

Comment: That's normal and completely fine, if it's the last line. Have you tried to backup your (%appdata%/).minecraft folder and then deleting it?

Answer (score 2):

There are two possible solutions. Try both and you should be good to go.

- Download the launcher again from [**minecraft.net**](http://www.minecraft.net/download).

Try to run Minecraft and if it still doesn't work do this:

- Press the Windows Key + R and type *%appdata%* in the small box.
- Locate the *.minecraft* folder and delete the *versions* folder inside of it.
- In some cases you might have to delete the whole *.minecraft* folder. In this case make a backup of it to save your resource packs and world saves before deleting it.

Now the game should work as intended.

Comment: What if I have already done everything stated in this list. Is it a problem with my computr now or is it a problem with my internet (although I doubt it), could it be the windows version I'm using?

Comment: It's not the internet connection (or very unlikely) as it's stuck locating local files. Possibly lacking permission to do so. Try to run the launcher as Administrator.

Comment: From what I have tested running the file as an administrator still gives me the same results.

Comment: What Java version do you have installed?

Comment: I have Java 8 Update 60 installed

Comment: One more possible way is to download and use the [minecraft.jar](https://s3.amazonaws.com/Minecraft.Download/launcher/Minecraft.jar) - if not check the launcher log for any errors and post them here (or edit them into your question)

Answer (score -7):

Try Restarting Your Computer, If It Doesnt Do Anything Try Deleting All Your Worlds.